# using grep on a specific file

Tags: grep

I've read, for instance [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode), that one could just run `M-x grep` to interface with the underlying shell and just run a simple `grep` command. I suspect something is wrong in the setup because this simple command does not work. Here's what I can see:

[image]

The command I type after `M-x grep` is

`grep 'Cell' input.scs`

It can be seen in the above screenshot right above the (garbled) `shell` prompt.

I don't know if that's a sign but it looks like the codes used to format the shell prompt are not totally understood by the `*grep*` buffer, but besides that, the process seems to stay in the "compiling" state forever, never returning any hit.

On the other hand, the very same command `grep 'Cell' input.scs` (you can see above the prompt) does work fine in a `shell` inside the directory this file is in.

Running `emacs -nw input.scs` returns basically the same output. Here I have used the command:

`grep -A1 'Cell' input.scs`

[image]

If I run `emacs -Q input.scs` to avoid loading of `init.el`, I still get the same result:

[image]

What can be possibly going wrong there?

Comment: You don't show the grep command you used with `M-x grep`. And say what `grep` you're using. And say whether you're using Emacs in terminal mode. Do you see this when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, normally (with most greps) it just works out of the box, and even if you try to grep binary files grep just tells you that a file is binary - it doesn't vomit terminal escape chars or binary data.

Comment: Also, please post only one question per post. I think your question is really about getting the Emacs `grep` command to work, and that has nothing to do with Dired. Please edit to just ask about your `M-x grep` problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @Drew, I will implement your suggestions. The grep command I have written explicitly and it is also visible in the screenshot, btw.

Comment: Regarding the color codes, I think it might require running `ansi-color-apply-on-region`, which is not an interactive command or other related `ansi-color-*` functions.

Comment: If it works in the shell within the file's directory, could it be that the default directory string in the GUI Emacs causing the problem?  We can't see it. Also, is it on a remote computer?

Answer (score 1):

press `A` to run `dired-do-find-regexp` in dired buffer

from its docstring:

> Find all matches for REGEXP in all marked files.
> If no files are marked, use the file under point.
> ..